# How to style a new added HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-lists

when I click the add button, a 'li' should be added to container2, this li has a class named 'obj' which I have styled in CSS, the list elements with the same class and which are already added in HTML code is styled well,  but the new elements added shows without any styling although they have the same class.

this is my js code:

```js
var bla;
$("#addButton").click(function() {

  if ($('#task').val() == '') {
    // alert('empty');
    $('#task').css("border-color", "#e40017");
    var msg = $("<div class='message'></div>").text('You should enter a task.');
    $(".container1").append(msg);

  } else {
    bla = document.getElementById('task').value;
    addDiv();
  }
});

function addDiv() {
  var task = $("<li class='obj'></li>").text(bla);
  $(".container2").append(task);
}
```

```css
.main-container {
  background-color: #c7cfb7;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container1 {
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #f7f7e8;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f7f7e8;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#container1-child1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#label1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#task {
  width: 250px;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  /* or whatever width you want */
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: grey;
}

#addButton {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #9dad7f;
}

.newTasks {
  border: 3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

.newTask {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #9dad7f;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.message {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-left: 85px;
}

.material-icons {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 5px;
}

.newTask:hover+.material-icons {
  visibility: visible;
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {}

ul li span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  margin-left: -45px;
  transition: 0.7s ease;
}

ul li:hover span {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container1">

  <label id="label1" for="task" class="inputlabel">Add a new task</label>
  <div id="#container1-child1">
    <input type="input " class="inputTask " name="task " id='task' required/>
    <button id="addButton">ADD</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container2" id="cont2">
  <ul>
    <li class="obj"> <span><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></span> get a new labtob</li>
    <li class="obj"> <span><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></span> get a new labtob</li>
    <li class="obj"> <span><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></span> get a new labtob</li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are appending it to `$(".container2").append(task);` whereas you want to append it to the `ul` inside the `container2`: `$(".container2 ul").append(task);`.

```js
var bla;
document.getElementById("addButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if ($("#task").val() == "") {
    // alert('empty');
    $("#task").css("border-color", "#e40017");
    var msg = $("<div class='message'></div>").text("You should enter a task.");
    $(".container1").append(msg);
  } else {
    bla = document.getElementById("task").value;
    addDiv();
  }
})

function addDiv() {
  var task = $("<li class='obj'></li>").text(bla);
  $(".container2 ul").append(task);
}
```

```css
.main-container {
  background-color: #c7cfb7;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container1 {
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #f7f7e8;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f7f7e8;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#container1-child1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#label1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#task {
  width: 250px;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  /* or whatever width you want */
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: grey;
}

#addButton {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #9dad7f;
}

.newTasks {
  border: 3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

.newTask {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #9dad7f;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.message {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-left: 85px;
}

.material-icons {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 5px;
}

.newTask:hover+.material-icons {
  visibility: visible;
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {}

ul li span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  margin-left: -45px;
  transition: 0.7s ease;
}

ul li:hover span {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">

  <label id="label1" for="task" class="inputlabel">Add a new task</label>
  <div id="#container1-child1">
    <input type="input " class="inputTask " name="task " id='task' required/>
    <button id="addButton">ADD</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container2" id="cont2">
  <ul>
    <li class="obj"> <span><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></span> get a new labtob</li>
    <li class="obj"> <span><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></span> get a new labtob</li>
    <li class="obj"> <span><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></span> get a new labtob</li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method in js file

```
function addDiv() {
        var task = $(`<li class='obj'> <span><i class='fa fa-trash '>${bla}</i></span> </li>`)
        $(".container2").append(task);
    };
```

And in CSS, replace ul li with li

```
li {
    list-style: none;
}

li span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    margin-left: -45px;
    transition: 0.7s ease;
}

li:hover span {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```